# Prevent animate RecycleView item multiple time

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have one `RecycleView`, in that category is display.

Also header and footer view for the screen. and `RecycleView` is between header and footer view.

By default header and footer visibility is `GONE`, but `RecycleView` Visibility in `VISIBLE`

When I set category data on `RecyclerView` it works fine and all items are animate single time.

But after category data set when I set header banners list and visible the header. at that time the recycleView is move down and all items are animate again.

So how to prevent that second time animation after visible other view in screen?

layout file :

```
        <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutBannerHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/banner_height"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_default"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerHeader"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <com.app.danube.utility.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/indicatorHeader"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_default"
                    app:fillColor="@color/purple"
                    app:pageColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:strokeColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layoutBannerHeader">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgCategory"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.app.danube.utility.MyRecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerSubCategory"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgSubCategory"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/sub_category_image_height"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutBannerFooter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/banner_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layoutContainer"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_default"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerFooter"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <com.app.danube.utility.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/indicatorFooter"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_default"
                    app:fillColor="@color/purple"
                    app:pageColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:strokeColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Header adapter

```
public class BannerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context mContext = null;
    private ArrayList<ClsBanner> bannerList = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;

    public BannerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ClsBanner> arrayList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.bannerList = arrayList;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bannerList.size();
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<ClsBanner> arrayList) {
        this.bannerList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_banner_image, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBanner);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(bannerList.get(position).getFileName()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_placeholder).into(imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mContext instanceof  HomeFragmentActivity)
                    ((HomeFragmentActivity) mContext).setBannerItemClick(bannerList.get(position));
                else if(mContext instanceof NotificationFragmentActivity)
                    ((NotificationFragmentActivity) mContext).setBannerItemClick(bannerList.get(position));
            }
        });

        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

category file

```
   public class SubCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements KeyInterface {
    private SubCategoryListFragment fragment = null;
    private ArrayList<ClsCategory> subCategoryList = null;

    public SubCategoryAdapter(SubCategoryListFragment fragment, ArrayList<ClsCategory> subCategoryList) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.subCategoryList = subCategoryList;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView txtTitle = null;
        private ImageView imgCategory = null;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            imgCategory = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCategory);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragment.itemClickListener(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_sub_category, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ClsCategory clsCategory = subCategoryList.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(clsCategory.getName());
        if (clsCategory.getCategoryId().equals("-1"))
            holder.imgCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else {
            holder.imgCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(clsCategory.getImage()).into(holder.imgCategory);
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(clsCategory.getImage()).asBitmap().listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.imgCategory.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    return false;
                }
            }).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    holder.imgCategory.setImageBitmap(resource);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subCategoryList.size();
    }

}
```

setting adapters.

```
RecyclerView recyclerSubCategory = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerSubCategory);
    recyclerSubCategory.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
    recyclerSubCategory.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(mContext, R.drawable.ic_list_divider));
    subCategoryAdapter = new SubCategoryAdapter(this, subCategoryList);
    recyclerSubCategory.setAdapter(subCategoryAdapter);



      viewPagerHeader = (AutoScrollViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerHeader);
        headerBannerAdapter = new BannerAdapter(mContext, headerBannerList);
        viewPagerHeader.setAdapter(headerBannerAdapter);

viewPagerFooter = (AutoScrollViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerFooter);
        footerBannerAdapter = new BannerAdapter(mContext, footerBannerList);
        viewPagerFooter.setAdapter(footerBannerAdapter);
```

now on WS call success.

```
if (subCategoryAdapter != null)
      subCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
callBannerListService();
```

on banner WS call.

```
 if (headerBannerAdapter != null)
        headerBannerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (footerBannerAdapter != null)
        footerBannerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (headerBannerList.size() > 0) {
        if (layoutBannerHeader != null)
            layoutBannerHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (viewPagerHeader != null) {
            viewPagerHeader.startAutoScroll((int) DELAY_MILLIS);
            viewPagerHeader.setInterval(BANNER_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
    }




if (footerBannerList.size() > 0) {
            if (layoutBannerFooter != null)
                layoutBannerFooter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (viewPagerFooter != null) {
                viewPagerFooter.startAutoScroll((int) DELAY_MILLIS);
                viewPagerFooter.setInterval(BANNER_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
        }
```

MyRecycleView

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private boolean mScrollable = false;

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return !mScrollable || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        Log.d("onLayout", "onLayout: ");
        if (!mScrollable) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                animate(getChildAt(i), i);

                if (i == getChildCount() - 1) {
                    getHandler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mScrollable = true;
                        }
                    }, i * 100);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void animate(View view, int pos) {
        Log.d("animate", "animate: " + pos);
        view.animate().cancel();
        view.setTranslationY(100);
        view.setAlpha(0);
        view.animate().alpha(1.0f).translationY(0).setDuration(300).setStartDelay(pos * 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide code how your work with RecyclerView

Comment: can you post your code.?

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin check edit on question.

Comment: This is because you have ovverride `onLayout` method in recycler view so it'll execute every single time whenever your screen get changed